# Prove that $\left(\prod\limits_{2<p}^{p_i} \frac{p-1}{p}\right) \cdot \left( p_{i + 1}^2 - p_i^2 \right) \geq \pi(p_{i + 1}^2) - \pi(p_i ^2)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers

Conjecture:

$$\left(\prod_{2<p}^{p_i} \frac{p-1}{p}\right) \cdot \left(p_{i + 1}^2 - p_i^2 \right) > \pi(p_{i + 1}^2) - \pi(p_i ^2) \tag{1}$$

The LHS expression is the product of Mertens's third theorem truncated at $p_i$ (subsequently just $M_x$ for truncation at $x$) times the length of the interval between the squares of $p_i$ and $p_i+1$, and the RHS is the *actual* number of primes between those squares. For instance, for $p_i = 7$, the expression is:

$$\frac{8}{35} \cdot \left(11^2 - 7^2\right) > \pi(121) - \pi(49)$$

And in fact $16.46 > 15$. Inequality $(1)$ is (perhaps surprisingly) *empirically* true for all $p_i$. The inequality seems *intuitively* likely to be true, as we would expect the result of $M_xx^2$ to be larger than $\pi(x^2)$ simply because $e^{-\gamma} > \frac12$ and therefore

$$\pi(x^2) \sim \frac{x^2}{\log x^2} = \frac12\frac{x^2}{\log x} < e^{-\gamma}\frac{x^2}{\log x} \tag{2}$$

(Inequality $(2)$ is empirically true only above $x \approx 100$, because the difference between $M_x \log x$ and $e^{-\gamma}$ is large for small $x$)

We can show ([much more easily than I expected, in this question where I briefly failed basic algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4016057/prime-counting-function-in-large-ish-intervals-two-questions-conjectures)) that the density of primes between $p_{i-1}^2$ and $p_i^2$ is lower than the density of primes between $0$ and $p_i^2$, that is:

$$\frac{\pi\left(p_{i+1}^2) - \pi(p_i^2\right)}{p_{i+1}^2 - p_i^2} < \frac{\pi(p_i^2)}{p_i^2} \tag{3}$$

With this, we expect difference between the LHS and RHS of $(1)$ to be greater than $(2)$ alone would imply.

But... I'm roughly 110% certain that $(2)$ and $(3)$ together don't qualify as *proof*. They *might* be proof of asymptotic behavior as $p_i \to \infty$, but I'm wondering if this can be (or already has been!) proven for smaller values. Any links or thoughts from the community?

Comment: $p_i+1$ or $p_{i+1}$? $(1)$ is clear, but the example after it for $p_i=7$ is confusing.

Comment: @rtybase Crud, yes, I missed putting the subscripts in properly. Darn Latex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(2)$ and $(3)$ can be combined to form a proof of the "for large enough $i$'s" style and everything else can be checked with a computer program.
$$\frac{\pi\left(p_{i+1}^2) - \pi(p_i^2\right)}{p_{i+1}^2 - p_i^2} < 
\frac{\pi(p_i^2)}{p_i^2}=
\frac{\pi(p_i^2)\cdot \log{p_i^2}}{p_i^2}\cdot \frac{1}{\log{p_i^2}}\leq ...$$
from [PNT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem), for large enough $i$'s we have
$\frac{\pi(p_i^2)\cdot \log{p_i^2}}{p_i^2}\leq 1+\varepsilon$, thus
$$...\leq \frac{1+\varepsilon}{2\log{p_i}}=
\frac{e^{\gamma}(1+\varepsilon)}{2(1-\varepsilon)}\cdot \frac{e^{-\gamma}\cdot (1-\varepsilon)}{\log{p_i}}\leq ...$$
from [Mertens' 3rd theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens%27_theorems), for large enough $i$'s we have
$\prod\limits_{p_i\leq p}\frac{p-1}{p}\geq\frac{e^{-\gamma}\cdot(1-\varepsilon)}{\log{p_i}}$, thus
$$...\leq \frac{e^{\gamma}(1+\varepsilon)}{2(1-\varepsilon)}\cdot\left(\prod\limits_{p_i\leq p}\frac{p-1}{p}\right) \tag{4}$$
What is left is to find a suitable $\varepsilon>0$ such that
$$\frac{e^{\gamma}(1+\varepsilon)}{2(1-\varepsilon)}<1 \iff
1+\varepsilon < \frac{2}{e^{\gamma}}\cdot(1-\varepsilon)$$
[which works](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%20%281%2B0.01%29%3C%202%2Fe%5EEulerGamma%20%281-0.01%29) for $e\leq0.01$ (it's easy to see that $f(x)=\frac{1+x}{1-x}$ is ascending).

Comment: Wow, that is impressive and elegant! I always forget that I can add $(1 + \epsilon)$ mostly at will in places. My calculations show this actually works for $\epsilon \leq 0.057$. I'm sure it's complete coincidence that it's almost exactly 10% of $\gamma$.  Is there any "standard" way of determining how large "sufficiently large" is for this sort of thing?

Comment: (Also, I assume that the range of "sufficiently large $x$" Would depend on the chosen $\epsilon$. Is that correct?)

Comment: Large $i$'s depends on $\varepsilon$, but you should take the $i_M=\max(i_{PNT},i_{M3RD})$, i.e. the maximum of $i$'s satisfying PNT and Mertens' 3rd theorem $\varepsilon$  constraints. Then $(1)$ will work for $\forall i\geq i_M$. The $1..i_M$ range can be checked with a (e.g.) Python code.

Comment: OK, I think I understand you there. Like I said in the OP, the inequality is true (empirically) for all $i$, so I don't think any programming is necessary. This really just proves a trivial upper bound (much higher than the PNT bound, I think), but it was mostly a thought exercise related to other stuff I'm studying. Reading your proof was really instructive, though!

Comment: @rtybase I am not quite sure, but how you proved $(3)$ ?, Assuming it true because $ \frac{\pi y}{y} < \frac{\pi x}{ x}$ for $y>>x$ does not imply it for $ x^{1+\epsilon} >>y>x$, for example $ \frac{\pi(p)+1}{p+2} > \frac{\pi p}{p}$ for all primes $p$ the smallest in twin primes pairs.

Comment: @Ahmad, that is a question to OP. But $$\frac{\pi\left(p_{i+1}^2) - \pi(p_i^2\right)}{p_{i+1}^2 - p_i^2} < \frac{\pi(p_i^2)}{p_i^2} \iff 
\frac{\pi\left(p_{i+1}^2\right)}{p_{i+1}^2} < 
\frac{\pi(p_i^2)}{p_i^2}\iff \\
\frac{\pi\left(p_{i+1}^2\right)\cdot\log{(p_{i+1}^2)}}{p_{i+1}^2} \cdot \frac{1}{\log{(p_{i+1}^2)}}< 
\frac{\pi(p_i^2)\cdot\log{(p_{i}^2)}}{p_i^2}\cdot \frac{1}{\log{(p_{i}^2)}}$$
which, considering PNT, is nearly 
$$\frac{1}{\log{(p_{i+1}^2)}}< 
\frac{1}{\log{(p_{i}^2)}}$$

Comment: @rtybase I know all of this, but it seems to me that you or OP assumed that $\frac{\pi x}{x}$ is non-increasing or behaving "well" in term of analytical functions which is far from the truth, this ratio oscillate up and down as graph and in very chaotic way, OP inequality seem to be true but I don't see a way from PNT you need RH or at least something stronger than PNT.

Comment: @Ahmad, yes, I definitely assumed it.

Comment: In the other question I linked ("where I briefly failed basic algebra"), it was pointed out that (3) is basic algebra (like 7th grade) hiding in plain sight. If we substitute letters to instead make the inequality $$\frac{a-b}{c-d} < \frac{b}{d}$$ then we have $d(a-b) < b(c-d) \iff ad - bd < bc - bd \iff ad < bc \iff \frac{a}{c} < \frac{b}{d}$, which is trivially and obviously true without assuming anything about $\pi(x)$, because $p_{i+1} > p_i$. (All the numbers involved are positive integers, so no worry about the direction of the inequality.)

Answer (score 1):

$\prod \limits_{2\leq p \leq p_i } (1-\frac{1}{p})  (p_{i+1}^2-p_{i}^2) \geq li(p_{i+1}^2)-li(p_{i}^2)$ for all $i \geq 4$

By noticing that $ \prod \limits_{2\leq p \leq p_i } (1-\frac{1}{p})  (p_{i+1}^2-p_{i}^2)  \approx \frac{e^{-\gamma}}{\ln p_i} (p_{i+1}^2-p_{i}^2)\geq  \frac{p_{i+1}^2-p_{i}^2}{2\ln p_i}\geq \int \limits_{p_{i}^2}^{p_{i+1}^2} \frac{dt}{\ln t}=li(p_{i+1}^2)-li(p_{i}^2)$

If you assume R.H. and let $ p_{i+i^{\epsilon}}^2-p_{i}^2$ with $i^{\epsilon} = O(\ln^k i)$ for $ k \geq 2$ then since $ |\pi(x)- li(x)| \leq \sqrt{x} \ln x$ this would imply the correctness of your conjecture for all $ i\geq 3000$ give or take according to the choice of $k$.

But without R.H. i don't see a way.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts! I'll admit I don't much understand anything after "If you assume RH"... I'm still trying to get my brain around even vaguely understanding the zeta equation let alone how it mixes with the primes :(. But it seems that your first inequality does *not* imply my inequality without RH is the basic gist.

Comment: The first inequality is true unconditionally, but your conjecture involves $\pi(x)$ and not $li(x)$ and since their difference change sign infinitely many times, without R.H. its hard (at least for me) to solve your conjecture, actually even when i assumed R.H. (Riemann hypothesis) i did solve somewhat weak version of your conjecture (lol).